# Android-json small issue

Tags: android

I have a json array equivalent to

```
{
"genre":"2",
"imported_from":"1",
"release_year":"1999",
"import":"1",
"label":"1",
"artist":"Boards Of Canada ", 
"album_title":"Music Has The Right To Children",
"formats":"1"
```

}

I am able to fetch the fields by

```
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

jsonObject.optString("genre");
```

But how can I access it by Index tried jsonObject.optInt(0); but does'nt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit: The reason that Android does not provide an API where you can use indexes is because in the JSON specification there is no order between tags, meaning that the "genre" tag will not always be the first element (this actually depends on the JSON parser used), so the following is a bad idea:*

It is not that efficient, but it works:

```
private int getInt(JSONObject jsonObject, int index) {
    int counter = 0;
    for(Iterator<String> i = jsonObject.keys(); i.hasNext(); ) {

        String item = i.next();

        if(counter == index){
            return jsonObject.optInt(item);
        }

        counter++;
    }

    return -1; //or default value/error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can only get the values by TAG_NAME only in Json Array because its a tag and that tag value its not a whole array of Json

```
{
"genre":"2",
"imported_from":"1",
"release_year":"1999",
"import":"1",
"label":"1",
"artist":"Boards Of Canada ", 
"album_title":"Music Has The Right To Children",
"formats":"1"
}
{
"genre":"2",
"imported_from":"1",
"release_year":"1999",
"import":"1",
"label":"1",
"artist":"Boards Of Canada ", 
"album_title":"Music Has The Right To Children",
"formats":"1"
}
{
"genre":"2",
"imported_from":"1",
"release_year":"1999",
"import":"1",
"label":"1",
"artist":"Boards Of Canada ", 
"album_title":"Music Has The Right To Children",
"formats":"1"
}
```

if you are something like this then from  index you get first index which is only first array(between two { } all tag and value) you get.